# Select radio button from RadioButtonList with URL

Tags: asp.net, post

I have a web form with a dynamically created `RadioButtonList`, a topic text box, a message text box, and a submit button. I need my monitoring from Solarwinds to be able to submit the form using the post method. I'm using `QueryString` for the text boxes, but I'm lost with the radio buttons. Is there a way to select a radio button via the URL and submit the form? Here is a sample of the generated HTML:

```
<input id="RadioButtonList1_0" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList1" value="value 1" /><label for="RadioButtonList1_0">Topic 1</label>

<input id="RadioButtonList1_1" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList1" value="value 2" /><label for="RadioButtonList1_1">Topic 2</label>
```

Comment: You should be able to add the selected radio button value to a hidden field, then grab that value with the post.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it seems I was making things way more complicated than they needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

This is all I needed. Having a slow day today!

`RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["selected"];`

www.myurl.com?selected=value 1